# Colon is not replaced by underscore in name of the property when passed to end-event script

Tags: alfresco, workflow-activity

I am trying to define workflow in Alfresco 4.2. I have a type defined as follows:

```
    <type name="abc:start">
        <parent>bpm:startTask</parent>
        <associations>
            <association name="abc:client">
                <source>
                    <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                    <many>true</many>
                </source>
                <target>
                    <class>cm:person</class>
                    <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                    <many>false</many>
                </target>
            </association>
        </associations>
    </type>
```

This type is used start event of an workflow:

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="activiti$sa05">
    <forms>
        <form>
            <field-visibility>
                <show id="packageItems" />
                <show id="abc:client"/>
            </field-visibility>
            <appearance>
                <set id="items" appearance="title" />
                <set id="info" appearance="title" />

                <field id="packageItems" set="items" />
                <field id="abc:client" set="info" />
            </appearance>
        </form>
    </forms>
```

In the event I have a very simple script (started at end of event), which uses this association:

```
logger.log("Starting workflow for: " + abc_client);
execution.setVariable("abc:client", abc_client);
```

When I start workflow for the first time, everything is ok. When I start it for the second time, I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute supplied script: 01240010 ReferenceError: "abc_client" is not defined. (AlfrescoJS#2)
```

I set a breakpoint in `RhinoScriptProcessor` and I was able to see that "abc:client" gets passed to script, rather then "abc_client". Why is it so? Why this isn't deterministic?

Comment: What is the value you were getting during successful run?

Comment: During the successful (=first) run I get "abc_client", which contains proper person data (as expected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the following line was problematic:

```
execution.setVariable("abc:client", abc_client);
```

Alfresco keeps an internal cache of two-way-mapping: qualified name <-> variable name. On first execution of workflow **{abc namespace}client** is mapped to **abc_client**. But then the above line gets executed and now **{abc namespace}client** is mapped to **abc:client**. As the result, on the next execution of the workflow `abc:client` is passed, rather then `abc_client`.